# Jekyll is printing HTML instead of rendering it

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I routinely use html tags to display images under Jekyll. However I am currently working on a new theme and the following image tag does not work.  Instead of showing the image, the resulting HTML page is displaying the tag itself.  I have not seen this problem before.  What am I missing?

`<img src="/assets/one.jpg" width=600> </img>`

Comment: Img tags in HTML are self closing so this is invalid: `</img>`. Your tag `<img src="/assets/one.jpg" width=600>` is perfectly valid though. Make sure you haven't indented or something else in your markdown so that it didn't trigger a markdown syntax other than inline code. It's worth sahring your markdown code you used in context so we can see if there is something else going on

Comment: Yes that really was the problem. I will delete the question.

Comment: No need to delete the question :) Was the problem the closing tag? I that case you should mark @bailey as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the end tag since it isn't required. `<img src="./assets/one.jpg" width=600>`